# Why does multiple AND condition on mysql does not meet the condition properly

Tags: mysql

I have question regarding on my MySQL script, I have module where I need to total all approvals based on the image that I example support to be the total is 2 however I got only count 1. I don't know where the condition wrong. based on my condition on my MySQL.

I have here my data.

[image: Data]

Here is my script that i create already.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as approverCounts
FROM xxxxxxx.evaluation_approval
WHERE approver_id = 5740 AND (isRejected = '0' AND for_re_evaluation = '0' AND for_approval = '1')
```

Output:
[image: My Script Output]

Comment: Only 1 row has `for_re_evaluation = '0'` the other is null.

Comment: what is the output now

Answer (score 1):

could be you have integer (or boolean) for isRejected , for_re_evaluation for_approval and not string so try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as approverCounts
FROM xxxxxxx.evaluation_approval
WHERE approver_id = 5740 
AND  isRejected = 0
AND for_re_evaluation = 0 
AND for_approval = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `OR` for your second condition

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as approverCounts
FROM xxxxxxx.evaluation_approval
WHERE approver_id = 5740 
AND (isRejected = '0' or for_re_evaluation = '0' or for_approval = '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your column `for_re_evaluation` can be `NULL` in your image:
It may be possible that you have to change `for_re_evaluation = '0'` to:
`(for_re_evaluation = '0' or for_re_evaluation IS NULL)`.
Or more simple (I think) to: `for_re_evaluation <> 1`

Comment: Seconds faster than me with `NULL` option xD

Comment: Yeah because I only provided the learning part, not the complete solution :D

Answer (score 1):

You have `null` in values so probably you want to compare to `null` too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as approverCounts
FROM xxxxxxx.evaluation_approval
WHERE approver_id = 5740 AND ((isRejected = '0' OR isRejected IS NULL) AND (for_re_evaluation = '0' OR for_re_evaluation IS NULL) AND for_approval = '1')
```